# Using MUI Autocorrect, with options populated by API

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I almost have a working solution, but the label aspect is giving an undefined error, and I also want to make sure my solution is elegant as its a component I will reuse a lot.

I have an API which returns a json response, and for the purposes of this, the important values are; (I will stub out the API and just provide its response).

```
const countries = 
[
  { country_id: 1, name: 'France', iso: 'fr'},
  { country_id: 2, name: 'Germany', iso: 'de'},
  { country_id: 3, name: 'United Kingdom', iso: 'gb'},
  { country_id: 4, name: 'Spain', iso: 'es'}
];
```

It's the MUI example with some tweaks to almost make it work as desired.

I want the label in the AutoComplete to be the country name, I want the value returned to be the `country_id` and the text in the AutoComplete to be the `name` of the Country they selected. It's the label that's not being set.

```
const Select = ({ country, onUpdate }) => { 
  //country is the valuable passed in to preselect an option or the option chosen, and the onUpdate is a function passed in (its a setState in the parent component).
 
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    api.get(`/countries`).then((response) => {
      if (response.data) {
        setCountries(response.data);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        autoHighlight
        fullWidth
        value={value}
        options={countries}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue.name);
        }}
        inputValue={country}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          onUpdate(newInputValue);
        }}
        renderOption={(props, country) => (
          <Box component="li" {...props}>
            {`{country.name} (${country.iso})`} 
          </Box>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Choose a country"
          />
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};


Select.propTypes = {
  country: PropTypes.string,
  onUpdate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Select;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line to your AutoComplete attributes:

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
```

---

According to the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#options-structure):

**Options structure**
By default, the component accepts the following options structures:

```
interface AutocompleteOption {
  label: string;
}
// or
type AutocompleteOption = string;
```

for instance:

```
const options = [
  { label: 'The Godfather', id: 1 },
  { label: 'Pulp Fiction', id: 2 },
];
// or
const options = ['The Godfather', 'Pulp Fiction'];
```

However, you can use different structures by providing a `getOptionLabel` prop.

---

Another option is to change the `name` property in your response object into `label` and you will be set.